# How to fix this: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python

```
student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split()

for n in range(0, len(student_heights)): 
  student_heights[n] = int(student_heights[n])

total_height =0
for i in student_heights:
    total_height += i
print(total_height)
```

Comment: what is the data you're providing in the input? If it's anything other than whitespaces and numbers it will throw the error

Comment: You can debug this by printing out each value of `student_heights[n]`. It seems you have a whitespace in `student_heights`.

Comment: @JeroenVerfaillie, I'm trying to input this list [156,178,165,171,187]

Comment: @GinoMempin, I tried using thonny to break the code down and what I  understand is that, the entire string of numbers I input reads as a single input

Comment: Are you inputting it with the square brackets `[ ]` and the comma `,`? Or just the numbers like this `123 456 789`? Because that's what your code does, it gets a single input string, and splits it on whitespaces to get a list of number strings. If you are inputting it with square brackets and commas... you'll have to fix your code because `split` is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the default behaviour of `split()` is to split by whitespace. You code would not throw errors if the input only contained numbers and whitespaces, e.g. `156 178 165 171 187`.

If you want a different split seperator, e.g. the comma `,`, you could use `split(",")` instead.

Valid input would be e.g. `156,178,165,171,187`.

Note that `[156,178,165,171,187]` is not valid input. It would split the string only at the comma, resulting in the first element to be equal to `[156`, clearly not a valid number.

If you want to skip the input step and use a list instead, replace:

`student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split()`

with:

`student_heights = [156,178,165,171,187]`

If you realy need to pass `[156,178,165,171,187]` as an input, you could also use `literal_eval` to convert it to a list. Don't forget to `import` the required module:

```py
from ast import literal_eval
student_heights = literal_eval(input("Input a list of student heights "))

for n in range(0, len(student_heights)): 
  student_heights[n] = int(student_heights[n])

total_height =0
for i in student_heights:
    total_height += i
print(total_height)
```

Comment: This Helps a lot. Thanks for helping me understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for n in range(0, len(student_heights)):
    if student_heights[n].isalpha():
        print("Enter only num's list, not letters")

        exit(1)

    student_heights[n] = int(student_heights[n])
```

Add `if student_heights[n].isalpha()` if is any letter in list of students height. 
(`isalpha()` is checking if are in your list/text are letters, if it is, it return **True**, if not **False**) 
`exit()`, if **True** it will exit.